Create .env file from all GitHub Actions secrets
I have a following GitHub Actions step that creates a .env file on the runner with all environment secrets to be used in a later step:
      - name: Create .env file with current secrets
        run: |
          cd ./${{ env.CI_JOB_ID }}
          touch .env
          echo API_KEY=${{ secrets.API_KEY }} >> .env
          echo TEST1_HOME_SERVER=${{ secrets.TEST1_HOME_SERVER }} >> .env
          echo TEST1_BOT_USERNAME=${{ secrets.TEST1_BOT_USERNAME }} >> .env
          echo TEST1_BOT_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.TEST1_BOT_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo ROOM_ID=${{ secrets.ROOM_ID }} >> .env
          echo ALLOWED_DOMAINS=${{ secrets.ALLOWED_DOMAINS }} >> .env
          echo SALT=${{ secrets.SALT }} >> .env
          echo TEST2_API_URL=${{ secrets.TEST2_API_URL }} >> .env
          echo TEST2_API_TOKEN=${{ secrets.TEST2_API_TOKEN }} >> .env
          echo TEST2_API_MODEL_NAME=${{ secrets.TEST2_API_MODEL_NAME }} >> .env
          echo TEST2_API_MODE=${{ secrets.TEST2_API_MODE }} >> .env
          cat .env

As you can see, I echo every single secret for now to the .env file. I could find some GitHub Actions steps that create JSON from all the secrets at once, but none that could create a .env file.
Is there any way to simplify that to get all the secrets at once and write them in an .env file?

You can use the Create .Env File GitHub Action for this. For example:
name: Create envfile

on: [ push ]

jobs:
  create-envfile:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 
    steps:
    - name: Make envfile
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v2.0
      with:
        envkey_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
        envkey_TEST1_HOME_SERVER: ${{ secrets.TEST1_HOME_SERVER }}
        envkey_TEST1_BOT_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.TEST1_BOT_USERNAME }}
        envkey_TEST1_BOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST1_BOT_PASSWORD }}
        envkey_ROOM_ID: ${{ secrets.ROOM_ID }}
        envkey_ALLOWED_DOMAINS: ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_DOMAINS }}
        envkey_SALT: ${{ secrets.SALT }}
        envkey_TEST2_API_URL: ${{ secrets.TEST2_API_URL }}
        envkey_TEST2_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TEST2_API_TOKEN }}
        envkey_TEST2_API_MODEL_NAME: ${{ secrets.TEST2_API_MODEL_NAME }}
        envkey_TEST2_API_MODE: ${{ secrets.TEST2_API_MODE }}
        directory: <directory_name>
        file_name: .env
        fail_on_empty: false
        sort_keys: false


Alternatively, you can use the GH CLI (which is automatically preinstalled in workflows) to fetch the secrets and then loop through them and add them to the env file.
Note that this requires setting up an admin token for the CLI to be able to list secrets.
References:

Using GitHub CLI in workflows
gh secret list command


It's not really shorter, one still has to write down each env var in the workflow, what is the advantage of this method?

It's at least more readable and maintainable. I don't think there is a shorter solution.

I read about that before posting the question, but adding a dependency doesn't make it more maintainable to me, and the whole thing is less readable to me, but that's subjective. I'm looking for a way to get all the secrets at once and write them at once. Thanks for the suggestion and time though!

@bolino just enhanced my answer with the other option that comes to my mind.

You can list the secrets, but can't download their values. Even with an admin token.

As a security feature there is no easy way to read the values of a secret unless it's explicitly mentioned or assigned in the workflow, either by:

Assigning an input
Assigning an environment variable
Referencing the secret inline in an input or script

A step doesn't get access to secrets that weren't exposed to it explicitly.
